# ArrayFire Installation Failure on MacOS

Tags: homebrew, gpu, arrayfire

I tried to install ArrayFire using the official installer, but it ended up with installation failure. Then, I tried to use homebrew to install, but `brew install arrayfire` gives this error:

```
Error: No available formula with the name "arrayfire"
```

I tried the instruction here:
https://github.com/arrayfire/arrayfire/wiki/Fixing-Common-OS-X-Installer-Failures
But, there is no error files.

Now, I have no idea what is going wrong. I am using a MacBook Pro 15 inch 2015 with MacOS High Sierra. It is the first time I try to install ArrayFire.

Comment: What error did you run into with the official installer?

Comment: @UmarArshad The installer only says "The installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail", without any specific detail. Is there a way to get more detailed error message? The error shows up during the installation when the installer is "validating the package".

Comment: The homebrew formula for ArrayFire used to be part of the now deprecated https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science. I do not know of any new attempts to package ArrayFire for homebrew. The official installer worked for me (similar hardware and also on High Sierra).

Comment: @RalfStubner Thanks for your information. It seems that there is something specific to my MacBook that causes the issue. I might just have to try on another PC then.